# Dynamic insertion of aurelia custom elements

Tags: aurelia

test.html

```
<gid>
  <grid-col prop1=""></grid-col>
  <grid-col-checkbox prop1=""></grid-col-checkbox>
  <grid-col-radio prop1=""></grid-col-radio>
  <grid-col-custom prop1=""></grid-col-custom>
</grid>
```

test.js
export class Test {}

==============

grid.html

```
 <table>
   <tbody>
     <td>test</td>
      =======
       <template classs="foo-class" repeat="">

       </template>
       ======
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

grid.js
      export class Grid {}

I want to insert the below things in table body. so that they will repeat for entire data

```
 <grid-col prop1=""></grid-col>
 <grid-col-checkbox prop1=""></grid-col-checkbox>
 <grid-col-radio prop1=""></grid-col-radio>
 <grid-col-custom prop1=""></grid-col-custom>
```

Can any one help how we can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a template for your table row:

my-table-row-template.html

```
<template>
    <td>
        <grid-col prop1=""></grid-col>
    </td>
    <td>
        <grid-col-checkbox prop1=""></grid-col-checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <grid-col-radio prop1=""></grid-col-radio>
    </td>
    <td>
        <grid-col-custom prop1=""></grid-col-custom>
    </td>       
</template>
```

**NOTE:** you can omit the `<td></td>` elements if they are already in your grid-col-x components

then to use just

```
<require from="my-table-row-template.html"></require>

<tr repeat.for="item of items">
   <my-table-row-template item.bind="item"></my-table-row-template>
</tr>
```

REFERENCE: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/doc/article/cheat-sheet/4